# Media Library Scheduled Task

Tags: kentico

We are using Kentico 11. I have configured our media library to use Azure CDN. Media files will be placed out there via CloudBerry Storage Explorer. It seems to take about 10 minutes for the Kentico UI media library to notice there are new files out there that need to be imported to the database. 2 questions...is there something I can do to make the process quicker (Kentico recognizing new files out there) and has anyone created a scheduled task that can be run to check for files in the CDN that are not yet in the Media_File table and import them automatically?

Thanks!